# <pidof> Command not showing all Java processes

Tags: process, java, pidof

I noticed that the  command in my case, is not listing all Java processes. If I run `pidof java` I get one single pid as a response. On the other hand, if I run `ps aux | grep [j]ava` I get a three different pids/Java processes. Any ideas on why this is?

Comment: Are they threads `ps` is exposing as processes?

Comment: @thrig They are 3 different Java processes. I beleive they are running on JBoss.